# Multipage Navigation, Command button to cycle through the Visible pages of the multipage in a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multipage that has 10 pages but some of them are hidden (visible=false).

Using a cmd button how would I cycle through the Visible ones

My code so far is

```
        cb1.Clear
        
         For i = 0 To 9
            If Me.MP1.Pages(i).Visible = True Then
                cb1.AddItem i
            End If
        Next
```

This puts the Visible page numbers in a combobox. How would I use a cmd button after that to change pages either forwards or backwards?

Answer (score 0):

well I figured it out here is the solution

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

```
    Dim temp1 As Integer
    
    
            temp1 = MP1.value

                temp1 = temp1 - 1
                If temp1 < 0 Then temp1 = 9
   Do
            If MP1.Pages(temp1).Visible = True Then
                MP1.value = temp1
                Exit Sub
            Else
                temp1 = temp1 - 1
            
            End If
            
    Loop
```

End Sub

then just make another for + and you should be good to go.